# tried ionic platform add android and got config.xml root name error

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I have been trying to add the android platform to ionic project but I keep getting the following error:

C:\Users\guizars\Desktop\ionicTest\weather>ionic platform add android

-Updated the hooks directory to have execute permissions

**C:\Users\guizars\Desktop\config.xml has incorrect root node name (expected "widg
et", was "config")**

can someone help me please??

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue to this, instead of the '(expected "widg et", was "config")' I was getting '(expected "widg et", was "platform")'.

To resolve this I opened my project config.xml and made sure that the last line was , placing any code I had added between the  and the ending .

I hope this helps and makes sense. I'm very new to this myself!

Comment: Please explain your answer

Comment: You need to make sure the config file ends in </widget>

Answer (score 0):

im stack to incorrect root node name
may help somebody ...

(config.xml has incorrect root node name (expected "widget", was "hook")